# Codeigniter custom route does it require a controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Ok I am trying to do some custom routing. Simple stuff so I thought. All I want to do is catch something like "home", "main", "logo" and remap them to go to a specific controller. However I plug the route in to the routes.php and when I go to domain.com/home I get a file not found error not even a 404

So my question is do I need a home, main, logo controller to support this or can it be done just the routes.

my routes.php currently looks like

```
$route['default_controller'] = "landing";
$route['404_override'] = '';
//custom routes
$route['home'] = "landing";
```

and heres the error page I am getting like I said not even the CI 404 error page you'd think you should get.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /home was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.20 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
>   mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server
>   at asylum.com Port 80

Comment: Could you post the `.htaccess` file you're using?

Comment: there is no current .htaccess, wasn't aware I needed one with CI

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.  With apache, you need an htaccess file to route all "missing" files to index.php

Comment: yea, thats the issue. I realized after awhile I had an htaccess file but i managed to over write it at one point with something else from a different project so I broke my own script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after someone reference. I realized I did have an .htaccess file, but. I must have overwritten its original contents thus breaking CI. After adding in a rewrite rule its been resolved

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```